# Remove compile option from linked INTERFACE library

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm working on a C/C++ project that depends on some external vendor libraries. I have the following project structure:

```
proj
|
|_ libs
|    |_ libA
|    |    |_ src
|    |    |_ inc
|    |
|    |_ libB...
|
|_ inc
|_ src
```

Now, **libA** be compiled on its own, except when toggling a given configuration option, which then makes it look for an externally provided "libA_alt.h". In this case, since libA is versioned in its own repo, *libA_alt.h* is provided under proj/inc.

I'm migrating this project from a Make build system to CMake, and I'm having issues in managing this situation.

So far I've tried the following solution:

- put a dedicated CMakeLists.txt in the libA project
- defined a library (called libA) in there, with the INTERFACE option
- put source files and necessary headers in there
- linked project against libA after adding it with `add_subdirectory(libs/libA)`. So far, so good.

Now, however, I added some extra compilation options to make the whole project compliant to a set of internally defined rules (akin to MISRA). The library, despite being provided by a reputable vendor and being used in a lot of products, is not compliant to a couple of these rules.
That's not big deal, because we don't feel the need to modify an externally developed library and we trust the code that comes with it, but now the library won't compile as (to my understanding) it inherits the compile options defined for **proj** due to its INTERFACE nature.

I tried the following `set_property(TARGET libA PROPERTY COMPILE_OPTIONS "")` in **proj** CMakeLists.txt to no avail, i.e. libA is still subjected to **proj** compile options.

How can I accomplish all of this in a more straightforward way?

**Edit:** I'm paraphrasing the main project CMakeLists, thanks @Chnossos for the suggestion

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION       3.25)
set(PROJ_ROOT                       ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})
include(cmake/toolchain.cmake       )

project(proj LANGUAGES C CXX ASM)

include(cmake/paths.cmake)
include(cmake/sources.cmake)
include(cmake/includes.cmake)
include(cmake/configuration.cmake)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD                17)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD_REQUIRED       ON)
set(CMAKE_C_EXTENSIONS              ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD              20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED     ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS            ON)
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS   ON)

add_subdirectory(libs/libA)
add_subdirectory(libs/libB)


# project_sources comes from sources.cmake and includes stuff in src
add_executable(proj ${project_sources})

# project_includes comes from includes.cmake and includes stuff in src
target_include_directories(proj PRIVATE ${project_includes})

# All of the options I want to enable on proj 
target_compile_options(boot PRIVATE
    -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard    
    -Wall
    -Wextra
    -Werror=conversion
    -Werror=sign-conversion
    -Werror=strict-overflow=3
    -Werror=shift-overflow=2
    -Werror=array-bounds=2
    -Werror=stringop-overflow=4
    -Werror=shift-count-overflow
    -Werror=vla
    -Werror=return-type
    -Werror=uninitialized
    -Werror=return-local-addr
    -Werror=double-promotion
    -Werror=float-equal
    -Werror=switch-default
    -Wshadow
    -Wcast-qual
    -Wundef
    -Wimplicit-fallthrough
    -Wlogical-op
    -Wduplicated-cond
    -Wduplicated-branches
    -Wcast-align=strict
    $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:C>: -Wjump-misses-init>
    -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fstack-usage -fsanitize=undefined

    $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CXX>:-fno-rtti -fno-exceptions>
    $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:ASM>:-x assembler-with-cpp -MMD -MP>

    $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:-Og -g3 -ggdb>
    $<$<CONFIG:Release>:-Os -g0>
)

target_link_libraries(proj libA libB)

set_property(TARGET libA PROPERTY COMPILE_OPTIONS "")

target_link_options(proj PRIVATE
    -T${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/foo/linker/linkerscript.ld
    -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard
    -Xlinker --gc-sections
    -static
    -Wl,-Map=proj.map
    --specs=nano.specs
    --specs=nosys.specs
    -Wl,--start-group
    -lc
    -lm
    -lstdc++
    -lsupc++
    -Wl,--end-group

)

add_custom_command(TARGET proj POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_SIZE} proj.elf
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_OBJCOPY} -O binary proj.elf proj.bin
)
```

Comment: How did you specify the options for `proj`? using `add_compile_options` or `target_compile_options`? Showing the skeleton of your CMakeLists might be useful to help you further.

Comment: CMake is parsed top to bottom, so if you `add_subdirectory` after setting variables, the subproject will "inherit" them also. Try adding libA before including your `.cmake` files for instance.

Comment: @Chnossos thanks for the suggestion. I've tried moving `target_compile_options` after `target_link_libraries(proj libA libB)` but it returns the same issue

Comment: All the `target_*()` commands are only applied to the specified target, so it was expected. I was rather talking about moving the `add_subdirectory()` command right under the `project()` command.

Comment: Got it, sorry for the misunderstanding. I've moved all `add_subdirectory` under `project`, followed by `include(xxx.cmake)` and `add_executable`. I've also moved `target_link_libraries` *before* `target_compile_options`, but it still returns the same problem

Comment: Alright. Just to be extra sure, you've completely deleted the build folder in-between each attempt right? CMake caches everything so without this, you might just be seeing the same result because of it.

Comment: @Chnossos yes, unfortunately I'd already tried deleting the cache and reconfiguring. I'm wondering if generator expressions might help to apply that option to everything but libA

Comment: There is no reason applying flags through `target_compile_options()` would reach linked targets at all. The problem comes from elsewhere but I'm sorry I can't help much from here.

Comment: @Chnossos I see, thank you anyway for your help! I figured it might be because of the CMakeLists within libA, that defines libA as add_library(libA INTERFACE)`. I'm relatively new to CMake but to my understanding in doing so I'm basically aggregating libA sources and includes to proj and subjecting them to proj's options